# Gradle, Kotlin : How to add another spring boot project as a module dependency in intellij

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, kotlin, build

I have two spring boot projects

```
Project1 (Spring boot project)
   |
   |--build.gradle
   |--settings.gradle
   |--src/main/kotlin

Project2 (Spring boot project)
   |
   |--build.gradle
   |--settings.gradle
   |--src/main/kotlin
```

Project2 is dependent on Project1. Could someone tell me how to add this dependency (e.g. modify build.gradle and settings.gradle) so that these projects should work fine. I have tried a lot of resources, but no luck to achieve that.

PS: Both Project1 and Project2 are spring boot Kotlin projects and they work fine individually. I want to reuse some functionality of Project1 into Project2 and I am not able to do it.

Also, Project1 and Project2 are at the same directory level.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: build `project2` as jar and add it as dependency

Comment: I am new to Gradle.. could you please give me the code as to how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

## Root project

As first step you need add root project with two subprojects.

#### `settings.gradle.kts`

```kotlin
rootProject.name = "demo-root"

include(
        "project1",
        "project2"
)
```

#### `build.gradle.kts`

```kotlin
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

plugins {
    base
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.3.71" apply true
    id("java-library")
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.2.6.RELEASE" apply false
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.0.9.RELEASE" apply false
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.jpa") version "1.3.71" apply false
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.3.71" apply false
}

allprojects {
    group = "com.dempcompany"
    version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

//    apply {
//        plugin("kotlin")
//    }

    tasks.withType<JavaCompile> {
        sourceCompatibility = "13"
        targetCompatibility = "13"
    }

    tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
        kotlinOptions {
            jvmTarget = "12"
        }
    }
}

subprojects {
//    apply {
//        plugin("io.spring.dependency-management")
//    }
}

dependencies {
    subprojects.forEach {
        // Make the root project archives configuration depend on every subproject
        archives(it)
    }
}
```

## Project1

Then configure build configuration for project1

#### `project1/build.gradle.kts`

```kotlin
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

plugins {
    base
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.3.71" apply true
    id("java-library")
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.2.6.RELEASE" apply false
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.0.9.RELEASE" apply false
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.jpa") version "1.3.71" apply false
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.3.71" apply false
}

allprojects {
    group = "com.democompany"
    version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

//    apply {
//        plugin("kotlin")
//    }

    tasks.withType<JavaCompile> {
        sourceCompatibility = "13"
        targetCompatibility = "13"
    }

    tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
        kotlinOptions {
            jvmTarget = "12"
        }
    }
}

subprojects {
//    apply {
//        plugin("io.spring.dependency-management")
//    }
}

dependencies {
    subprojects.forEach {
        // Make the root project archives configuration depend on every subproject
        archives(it)
    }
}
```

#### `project1/setting.gradle.kts`

```kotlin
rootProject.name = "project1"
```

## Project2

And then configure build configuration for project2

#### `project2/build.gradle.kts`

```kotlin
plugins {
    id("org.springframework.boot")
    id("io.spring.dependency-management")
    kotlin("jvm")
    kotlin("plugin.spring")
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven("https://jitpack.io")
}

java.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_13

dependencies {
    /* Project modules */
    implementation(project(":project1", "default"))

    /* Spring Framework */
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
    
    /* Kotlin */
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.3.3")
}
```

#### `project2/settings.gradle.kts`

```kotlin
rootProject.name = "project2"
```